# Better way to pass default arguments to subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super

Suppose I have some class which I subclass, that has some default (perhaps a flag-like) argument. What's the best way to handle passing such an argument around? I can think of doing

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, noisy = False):
        self.noisy = noisy

    def bark(self):
        if self.noisy:
            print('YAP')
        else:
            print('yap')

class Beagle(Dog):
    def __init__(self, noisy = False):
       super().__init__(noisy)
    
dave = Beagle(noisy = True)
dave.bark()
```

But this uses `noisy` seven times, and I feel there must be a better way.

Comment: You mean superclasses maybe?

Comment: That's the way you do it.  What don't you like about that?  Note that, if `Beagle` doesn't need any other `__init__` processing, you can skip the function altogether, and it will inherit the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can drop the `noisy =` in the instantiation of `Beagle()`, it's unneeded:

```
dave = Beagle(True)
```

Secondly, given your implementation, your `Beagle` class has no reason to exist. It does not add any functionality and does not specialize `Dog` in any way. If anything, possible subclasses of `Dog` that make sense would be:

```
class NoisyDog(Dog):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__(True)

class QuietDog(Dog):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__(False)
```

You could also keep the `noisy=` in the calls to `super().__init__()` for better readability, but again that's unneeded.

Other than that, there isn't really much else you can do. If you need a class property, you'll have to assign it to the class (`self.foo = bar`) and then reference it using its name...

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration, I think I will use those short subclasses in future, nice.